# Require user to be in particular area for app to load

Tags: ios, core-location

I have been looking into getting the user's location and then verifying they are in a particular building, and then loading the app. I have been experimenting with `CoreLocation` but cannot find any cases where this location verification is true. I was thinking the easiest way would be an if/else statement but I need the location to do that. I want this to be compatible with as many `iOS` devices as possible, so backwards compatibility is something I am interested in too.

Comment: This question is very broad. Are you having trouble reading the users location? Or verifying that it's in a particular area?  Please provide some of your code to help clarify

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do, there are tons of tutorial that'll show you how to do this. The gist of it is:

- Register app to use location in the background.
- Ask permission to use location all the time.
- Create the region that you want to use to wake the app up.
- Start monitoring for location changes to that region.
- The app will relaunch when the user enters that region and calls `appDidFinishLaunching`, then you can do your thing.